# Audio recording in ogg format ios

Tags: ios, audio-recording

I am developing an iOS application and it has brought me at a point that em stuck.. I have to do audio recording in `.ogg` format as i have to send it over to a web module.. I am able to record in `.m4a` format with a very good compression and size but now i have to deliver it in .ogg format..

I have searched alot on the internet and havent found any good solution or way to do so.

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, have you solved this?

Comment: Hi, I did solve it long time ago.. But currently I dont remember what I did .. Sorry